# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException on jaxws client with ws-addressing feature

Tags: tomcat, client, jax-ws, dispatch, ws-addressing

I've got the gollowing problem in invoking a web service with jaxws client, running in Tomcat

the code is as follow:

```
    javax.xml.namespace.QName portQname = new javax.xml.namespace.QName("urn:hl7-org:v3","PRPA_AR201302UV02_Service");
    javax.xml.ws.Service service = javax.xml.ws.Service.create(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("urn:hl7-org:v3","PRPA_AR201302UV02_Service"));
    service.addPort(portQname,javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING,wsaddress);


    Dispatch<Object> dispatch =service.createDispatch(portQname,jaxbContext,javax.xml.ws.Service.Mode.PAYLOAD,new javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature());


    dispatch.getRequestContext().put(javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_USE_PROPERTY,true);
    dispatch.getRequestContext().put(javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY,"urn:hl7-org:v3:PRPA_IN201301UV02");
```

The code works properly with ws-addressing features, when I run it from Eclipse run Tool, without providing an axis2.xml file

When I run it inside a Tomcat instance it gives me the following exception

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Error getting Client Configuration Context : The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: addressing
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getClientConfigurationContext(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:92)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactory.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.(ServiceDelegate.java:218)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:79)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:92)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:756)
    at wgs.v3.client.impl.V3ClientNoWsdl.callMethod(V3ClientNoWsdl.java:128)
    at wgs.v3.client.impl.V3ClientNoWsdl.invoke(V3ClientNoWsdl.java:89)
    at wgs.tx.dispatcher.Sender.elab(Sender.java:204)
    at wgs.tx.dispatcher.Sender.elab(Sender.java:158)
    at wgs.tx.system.MessageDispatcherSender.processRequest(MessageDispatcherSender.java:159)
    at wgs.tx.system.MessageDispatcherSender.run(MessageDispatcherSender.java:99)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)

Did anybody issue the same problem? I can't get out of this

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The Eclipse run tool was not based on axis2 implementation of jax-ws standard but on the stand alone distribution.

To have the same classes running properly on Tomcat with axis2 I had to add the following line 
before creating the service instance

```
System.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.Constants.AXIS2_REPO, getServletContext().getRealPath(FILE_SEPARATOR) + FILE_SEPARATOR + "WEB-INF");
```

So that axis2 implementation can access correctly the modules and configuration dirs.